# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to use react router in one of my application. But am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined
```

on line

```
var DefaultRoute = React.createClass({ ..
```

The code I have been writing is

```
var Q                       = require('q'), 
    doThis                  = require('./generic/modules/doThis.js'),
    doThat                  = require('./generic/modules/doThat.js');
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var Redirect = Router.Redirect;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;

var aModule = require('./modules/aModule/aModule.js');
var Master = require('./modules/master/master.js');

var injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin');

(function (){

    var routes = (
        <Route name="root" path="/" handler={Master}>
            <Route name="time" handler={aModule} />
        </Route>);
    window.React = React;
    injectTapEventPlugin();

    var doThisPromise = doThis.init();
    doThisPromise.
    then(function() {
        doThat.init();
        Router.run (routes, function(Handler) {
            console.log('in router run');
            React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
        });
    }, function (err) {

    });
})();
```

If necessary please ask and I will also provide the route related js

-- EDIT --
The relevant error code from the build file

```
},{}],84:[function(require,module,exports){
var React = (window.React);
var FakeNode = require('../mixins/FakeNode');
var PropTypes = require('../utils/PropTypes');

/**
 * A <DefaultRoute> component is a special kind of <Route> that
 * renders when its parent matches but none of its siblings do.
 * Only one such route may be used at any given level in the
 * route hierarchy.
 */

var DefaultRoute = React.createClass({

  displayName: 'DefaultRoute',

  mixins: [ FakeNode ],

  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    path: PropTypes.falsy,
    handler: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

});

module.exports = DefaultRoute;
```

Comment: Check that `require('react')` is returning what you expect it to. Also I don't see `DefaultRoute = React.createClass` anywhere in your code. I see `DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute`, are those supposed to be the same?

Comment: Yes, react is consoling it correctly as expected. 
The DefaultRoute is not my code. Its the react router code.

Comment: So the code that is causing and error is in `require('react-router')` and not to code that you are showing us?

Comment: What react and react-router version are you using?  Also, try removing node_modules and reinstalling.  This is a very weird issue.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek : Basically, Yes :)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand :     "react": "^0.12.2",   "react-router": "^0.11.6",

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand :  Tried reinstalling the modules. Still the same problem

Comment: I have no idea what could be going wrong here.  You can't replace the exports of a module externally.  Whatever's going on is really crazy.

Comment: I have attached the relevant piece of code. Yes, it is weird that it cannot find React. Whereas in the build code it is clearly added the way it should be.